# Marsh ~ Swamp ~ Bog

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I am going through the word

> 沼泽 zhǎozé marsh, swamp, bog

Tried to find out the meanings for 3 of them as below:

Marsh

> an area of low-lying land which is flooded in wet seasons or at high tide, and typically remains waterlogged at all times.
> "the marsh marigold loves damp fields, riverbanks, and marshes"

Swamp

> an area of low-lying, uncultivated ground where water collects; a bog or marsh.

Bog

> an area of wet muddy ground that is too soft to support a heavy body.
> "a peat bog"

What is the difference among these three? In my native language the word used for uncultivated ground (next to the cultivated land is called “Alugu” and you can not use this word for other wetlands.

Comment: You first have to realise that they're close or reasonably close synonyms, which means that in many everyday sentences they will be interchangeable without even a subtle change in meaning. 'The faint trail through the forest was descending, and we soon realised we were heading into a ____.' Kate has pointed towards stipulating definitions, but these really belong on geography sites. 'Ombrotrophic bogs', for instance. [The U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service](https://www.epa.gov/wetlands/classification-and-types-wetlands#marshes) (EPA) has an article titled 'Classification and Types of Wetlands'.

Comment: As the dictionary definitions you give show the synonymity in everyday usage, and the article shows that stipulating definitions are not only esoteric but also conflicting, I've CV-d; 'open to opinion' is the reason I've gone with.

Comment: I disagree with the person who had closed saying it is opinion based. There were differences even in my native language we have different word for Swamp and we can not use that word to 2 other meanings. @Edwin Ashworth, is it you closed the question?

Comment: The information at [Knowledgenuts.com/marsh vs swamp vs bog vs fen](https://knowledgenuts.com/marsh-vs-swamp-vs-bog-vs-fen/#:~:text=Marshes%20are%20nutrient%2Drich%20wetlands,plant%20life%20than%20a%20bog.) will probably interest you, but again this might not agree totally with other articles. And it's really beyond the remit here, being so scientifically orientated. I'd associate a swamp with trees, often jungle, and see a swamp as usually more liquid than a bog. Bogs can be small areas, but can be extensive (eg Irish peat bogs).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, It is not opinion based, your way of closing question Is not correct, I think if you do not know the answer, you are closing. not correct

Comment: Have you tried checking the etymology of 3 words, before closing?

Comment: This question should definitely be reopened. There are differences in meaning between these words based on common usage. For example, we can get “bogged down” at work, or “swamped”, but the associated mental images are different. We typically don’t get “marshed”. We use the words differently because they correspond to different physical environments, and our sense of being able to travel through them is different.

Comment: @user27485 That's basic research. Please check site recommendations. / Checking differences of meaning, perhaps nuanced, between **three** words is also stretching the 'one question at a time' ruling. But there _are_ different emphases in the definitions OP provides, though the words are obviously said to be synonyms. The answers will depend on which definitions (dictionary or stipulating) one chooses. // One fails to see what relevance etymologies have. Modern usage trumps etymology every time. _The etymological fallacy._

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth pls put your research in the answer form, and re-open as it is not opinion based first. Please see how kate had answered beautifully her answer.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth what made you think, it was opinion based? and closed? the link clearly states the difference

Comment: I think this is a poorly-worded question, as it doesn't provide any indication of the *context* in which the word will be used. The specificity of the term will depend heavily on whether you're using it in a scientific sense (e.g. what kind of plants grow in the defined environment), or in common English ("my front yard looks like a ____"), or metaphorically ("my sentence turned into an adverb ____"). Please [edit] your post to provide the necessary detail. :-)

Comment: Please keep things clear. I close-voted because I believed that answers were 'open to opinion'; Chappo, above, has explained why. In everyday English, the terms are often interchangeable, as the dictionary definitions show. In GCSE biology, the terms may be differentiated perhaps to the level I mentioned 'I'd associate a swamp with trees, often jungle, and see a swamp as usually more liquid than a bog. Bogs can be small areas, but can be extensive (eg Irish peat bogs)'. The Knowledgenuts article would help here, perhaps. But when ...

Comment: one gets to the stipulative definitions chosen by the boffins, for instance the multi-layered classification of marshes, swamps, bogs _and_ fens  used by the  U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service, one is into geography not everyday English. And doubtless some other well-researched classification scheme will clash with the one favoured by the USFWS, and terminology will at time contradict everyday usages. Hence, open to opinion: whose terminology should we choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. In my everyday British English, I might describe a patch of soft ground as either *boggy* or *marshy,* but from a scientific point of view *marshes* are coastal or riverside wetlands, and *peat bogs* are acidic areas of ancient rotting vegetation, often on higher ground. I found various sites by searching 'difference between marsh and swamp', such as [this one](https://knowledgenuts.com/marsh-vs-swamp-vs-bog-vs-fen/)

Comment: Marshes are nutrient-rich wetlands that support a variety of reeds and grasses, while swamps are defined by their ability to support woody plants and trees. Bogs are characterized by their poor soil and high peat content. I also have the same query, the above explains the difference in a nutshell.. Thanks